# (My)SQL: How to count how many messages one ticket contains that adhere to a certain condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got two tables in my database:

```
ticket
  - id
  - customer_id

message
  - id
  - ticket_id
  - supporter_id
```

if a message was from the customer the supporter_id field is null, otherwise it contains (as you would expect) the supporter id.

I now want to know how many tickets there are with only one message in it with a supporter_id field which is not null (i.e. I'm looking for the tickets which were solved with only one message from the supporter, or the "one-time fix" percentage). And I also want to know what the percentage of "one-time fixes" is for every supporter.

I guess I need to use joins or something, but I'm kinda lost in that. Does anybody know how I should tackle this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for that. If I understand you correctly, you want:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message WHERE ticket_id = ticket.id AND supporter_id IS NOT NULL
) = 1
```

This will fetch all tickets where only a single message with a non-null supported_id exists.

Using this, you should be able to figure out how to calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is:

```
SELECT COUNT(ticket_id)
FROM (
   SELECT ticket_id
   FROM message
   WHERE supporter_id is NOT NULL
   GROUP BY ticket_id
   HAVING COUNT(*)=1
);
```

The usual vaveat regarding performance tuning applies - do you need to see all your data and does this really solve your problem?